# How can warm steel and wood merge together?

Tags: iron

I need to describe the manufacturing of japanese knives. I struggle with the step when the steel blade is put together with the wooden handle.
Here are some pictures from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2L_Ku47afo (at 6'42"):

[image: Merging between warm steel and wood]

After putting the hot blade inside the handle, you can see that the steel immediately cools down and after hitting the handle with a hammer, the two pieces are merged. I've been told that the welding could not function between two different materials, especially not wood. **Could you please explain me how those two materials merge together in this situation please ?**

Thanks in advance for your answers !

**EDIT:**

1. Sorry if this doesn't seem directly related to chemistry, I was more interested of what happened in the molecular scale than the physic reactions, if you think about a better forum to ask this do not hesitate to tell it to me;
2. For those who can't see the picture or the video, the blacksmith has made a very long, thin end to the steel blade which he has warmed up until it becomes orange and then he puts it inside the wooden handle (which has a drilled hole). After he did this you can see smoke going out the handle, and finally the blacksmith hits the handle with a hammer (in the direction of the length).

Comment: It looks to me that wood, heated up by steel, undergoes in various extend plastic mechanical deformation and thermal decomposition, releasing space for the steel object.

Comment: There is already a drilled hole in the wood when the steel is inserted in it, how do you think those reactions could prevent the blade from getting out this hole ? And why the hammer ?

Comment: Plasticity goes either way, together with possibility of making wood to stick to steel.

Comment: I think it is a "press fit" , mechanical. The pilot hole is smaller than the tang. The hot tang burns a hole that is just the right size.

Comment: As I mention in my comment to blacksmith37's answer, below, there is possbility that the heat creates some melting in the wood, and this causes a bonding to the metal.  We know that wood contains lignins and other components that, under the right conditions, can melt to form bonds to itself (see youtube.com/watch?v=X0k04hjdYuQ and link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00226-006-0097-2). So I'm wondering if the wood might also be able to melt slightly to bond to the metal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common press fit , no chemistry involved. Most commonly used for files (in US). All my files (old) use this same press fit, I believe newer files have plastic handles. The use of heat to custom shape the hole for the tang is a good modification. A smaller pilot hole can be used because it will be enlarged to the right size by burning. This likely gives a tighter fit compared to a larger round hole

Comment: What about the possbility that there is welding involved? Wood contains lignins and other components that, under the right conditions, can melt to form bonds to itself (see youtube.com/watch?v=X0k04hjdYuQ and link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00226-006-0097-2). So I'm wondering if the wood might also be able to melt slightly to bond to the metal.